# Is it reasonable to put nginx in front of nodejs to serve static assets?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Is it reasonable to put nginx in front of nodejs to serve static assets?

Comment: That reads to me like you want nodejs to serve static assets, but I assume you mean nginx is serving the static assets?

Comment: Yes, the title could be misunderstood. I suggest to rewrite it to "Is it reasonable to put nginx in front of nodejs to serve static assets?". Even better would be to have an open question, and not a yes/no question. Also, it would help if you would add some details about the characteristics of your application, load, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do that. I like using Node with Express and the thin stack that results. I believe with early versions of Node using a web server like Nginx was recommended due to performance concerns. I'm not sure that's valid anymore.

Comment: Why are you using two accounts to answer the same question? Why do you even have multiple active accounts?

Answer (score 4):

I asked on #node.js irc and Ryan replied for security - "you just may be hacked when some yet-unknown buffer overflow is discovered. Not that that couldn't happen behind nginx, but somehow having a proxy in front makes me happy".

That said is you use a hosted Node service like joyent No.de default app runs on port 80 without Nginx as far as I know.

To setup Node with Nginx see: http://wellconsidered.be/nodejs-on-nginx